# Python MPI.reduce do not work

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi

```
from mpi4py import MPI
import json
import numpy as np

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
comm_rank = comm.Get_rank()
comm_size = comm.Get_size()

comm.Barrier()

FINAL_RESULT =[]

#Parent process
if (comm_rank == 0):
    print "There are %d cores" % comm_size
    with open('tinyTwitter.json','r') as f:
        coor = json.load(f)

    with open('melbGrid.json','r') as g:
        grid = json.load(g)


    ## Broadcast the coordinate
    Coordinate = []
    ## Loop through each item 
    n = len(coor)
    for i in range(0,n):
        ##Determine which grid the item is sent from
        y = coor[i]['json']['geo']['coordinates'][0] ## latitude
        x = coor[i]['json']['geo']['coordinates'][1] ## longtitude
        Coordinate.append([x,y])
    local_Coordinate = np.array(Coordinate)



    local_Grid_Info = [] ## A List to store the grid information

    ##Extrating the boundary coordinates of each grid
    size = len(grid['features'])
    for i in range(0,size):
        Grid_dict = {}
        Grid_id = grid['features'][i]['properties']['id']
        xmin = grid['features'][i]['properties']['xmin']
        xmax = grid['features'][i]['properties']['xmax']
        ymin = grid['features'][i]['properties']['ymin']
        ymax = grid['features'][i]['properties']['ymax']
        Grid_dict[Grid_id]={'xmin': xmin ,'xmax' : xmax , 'ymin': ymin , 'ymax' : ymax} ## [ {A1:{'xmin':...}},A2:{'xmin'},...]
        local_Grid_Info.append(Grid_dict)
    local_Grid_Info = np.array(local_Grid_Info)


#Broadcast the data to slaves   
local_Coordinate = comm.bcast(local_Coordinate if comm_rank ==0 else None,root = 0)
local_grid = comm.bcast(local_Grid_Info if comm_rank == 0 else None,root = 0)



#child process
if(comm_rank > 0):  
#print local_Coordinate       
    ## The result table
    local_Result = {}

    ## Initialize the result dictionary
    for i in local_grid:
        for grid_id in i:
            local_Result[grid_id] = 0          
    local_Result['A-Row'] = 0
    local_Result['B-Row'] = 0
    local_Result['C-Row'] = 0
    local_Result['D-Row'] = 0
    local_Result['Col-1'] = 0
    local_Result['Col-2'] = 0
    local_Result['Col-3'] = 0
    local_Result['Col-4'] = 0
    local_Result['Col-5'] = 0

##    print local_Result

    #Evenly split the input coordinate to different processes based on their rank
    start = (comm_rank - 1)*len(local_Coordinate)/(comm_size-1)
    end = (comm_rank)*len(local_Coordinate)/(comm_size-1)



    for i in range(start,end):
        x = local_Coordinate[i][0]
        y = local_Coordinate[i][1]

        #Determine the location of the point
        for one_grid in local_grid:  #index in a list to fetch a dic
            for (k,v) in one_grid.items(): # a dictionary
            # Single  Grid Calculation
                if(y >= v['ymin'] and y <= v['ymax'] and
                   x >= v['xmin'] and x <= v['xmax']):
                    ## Append to the local_Result dictionary
                    local_Result[k] = local_Result[k] + 1
                    break;

    local_Result['A-Row'] = local_Result['A1']+local_Result['A2']+local_Result['A3']+local_Result['A4']
    local_Result['B-Row'] = local_Result['B1']+local_Result['B2']+local_Result['B3']+local_Result['B4']
    local_Result['C-Row'] = local_Result['C1']+local_Result['C2']+local_Result['C3']+local_Result['C4']+local_Result['C4']
    local_Result['D-Row'] = local_Result['D3']+local_Result['D4']+ local_Result['D5']
    local_Result['Col-1'] = local_Result['A1'] + local_Result['B1'] + local_Result['C1']
    local_Result['Col-2'] = local_Result['A2'] + local_Result['B2'] + local_Result['C2']
    local_Result['Col-3'] = local_Result['A3'] + local_Result['B3'] + local_Result['C3'] + local_Result['D3']
    local_Result['Col-4'] = local_Result['A4'] + local_Result['B4'] + local_Result['C4'] + local_Result['D4']
    local_Result['Col-5'] = local_Result['C5'] + local_Result['D5']
    print local_Result
    r = [k for (v,k) in local_Result.items()]
    r = np.asarray(r)
    print r
    comm.Reduce(r, FINAL_RESULT, op=MPI.SUM, root = 0)

comm.Barrier()
print FINAL_RESULT




##
##for key in Result:
##    print key +":" + str(Result[key])   
##
##if (comm_rank == 0):
##    exit(0)
```

Hello, I am doing a coordinate extraction from JSON file and then classify then base on their geographical location on the map.
Each process is intended to calculate how many points are within the particular grid and I would like the main process to sum up all the result.
However, when I try to do `comm.Reduce()` at the very end, I found out that  `FINAL_RESULT`is blank.
For example , I run `mpiexec -np 2 python p.py`,
 I will get r as 
`[ 4 53  0  2  2  0 15 50  1  1  7  7 80  8 88 29 11  2  2  7 36  8  2  1  4]`
Whereas `mpiexec -np 3 python p.py` gives

```
[ 2 25  0  1  1  0  9 22  1  0  2  3 36  6 35 18  4  1  2  5 12  6  0  1  2]
[ 2 28  0  1  1  0  6 28  0  1  5  4 44  2 53 11  7  1  0  2 24  2  2  0  2].
```

The `FINAL_RESULT` is `[]`.
I would like to know how I should combine the two processes' result together or at least send back to the master at `FINAL_RESULT`
Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reduction call is within the body of the `if(comm_rank > 0):` conditional, which means that at least one process does not participate in the collective reduction call. It happens that this process is no other but the designated root rank of 0, therefore nothing gets stored in `FINAL_RESULT` because the root never receives anything from the worker processes. The `comm.Reduce` statement should be outside of the conditional block.